# svn externals not adding all files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have an external app_code folder shared among multiple projects. I have noticed that when I do an svn update using tortoise svn that not all the files within the folder get added to my app_code working folder. If I delete the whole folder and do an update all files are added. This happens on all folders that are external. Any help on how to work around this problem would be great. We have quite a few files in this folder and it is a pain to have to delete it everytime we want to get newer files.

External definition:
app_code http://yversion/repos/app_code/Trunk
 
app_controls http://yversion/repos/app_controls/Trunk 
app_themes http://yversion/repos/app_themes/Trunk 
bin http://yversion/repos/bin/Trunk 
pagesMaster http://yversion/repos/Masterpages/Trunk 
App_WebReferences http://yversion/repos/App_WebReferences/Trunk

Thanks
 
Royal

Comment: have you tried re-checking out your entire working copy? sometimes that resolves random-seeming issues with svn.

Comment: Can you indicate what version you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your repositories have different uuids.

Comment: All folders are in the same repository so am assuming the uuuids is the same.

Comment: The main issue seems to be that the folder doesn't get updated but if I delete it and do an update on the main folder all the files get added in.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but just in case anybody comes across it in a search, I was able to resolve this by running 'svn cleanup' on the root folder of the project.